# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 ,com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver not found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, odbc-sql-server-driver

Have installed mobile first 7.1 ,Have pushed the adapters successfully.But while making adapter call,getting error **com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver not found In Work light or Project Work space.**

After search have tried many option , have added the sqljdbc4.jar file in server/lib folder of project, also added in lib of JDK. Also added the path of  sqljdbc4.jar as Class Path in System Variable.

PS- My environment is as follows, IBM MobileFirst 7.1, jdk1.8.0_181, windows 10

Comment: Is this issue in your MFP Studio? Or in a standalone installation.

Comment: have installed MF 7.1 CLI alone

Comment: Did you do mfp push from the root of the project and ensure the modified war file got deployed?